# How can i display total number of records in repeator, asp.net...?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I am using Repeater in asp.net, i want to display total number of records.
I have used Repeator1.Items.Count in databound, but its problem is, if some one submits button then as repeater loads just once and reloads only on change in its items, so my total items remain there, even if there is no record in search, but when repeater loads with some different result then again total items appear. Please let me know the solution.

Thanks
Atif

Comment: How you add to `repeater Data-Source`>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call the Control.DataBind method before you get the item count